# Accessing A GPU in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gpu

I have free credit account on Google Cloud Platform. I want to access a GPU for training my deep learning project. I even submitted different quota requests, but every time it got rejected. Do I need to pay some money to GCP to access a GPU? How can I do that? Here is the reply that I got from Google every time,"We have received your quota request for deep-learning-261006.

Unfortunately, we are unable to grant you additional quota at this time. If 
this is a new project please wait 48h until you resubmit the request or 
until your Billing account has additional history.

Your Sales Rep is a good Escalation Path for these requests, and we highly 
recommend you to reach out to them."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not Google customer support.

Comment: Questions asking for [*customer support with third-party services*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745) (such as App Stores) are off-topic for Stack Overflow. Instead, please direct your questions to the relevant company/organisation's technical support team.

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier):

Program coverage

- You can't have more than 8 cores (or virtual CPUs) running at the same time.
- **You can't add GPUs to your VM instances.**
- You can't request a quota increase. For an overview of Compute Engine quotas, see Resource quotas.
- You can't create VM instances that are based on Windows Server images.

You'll be able to add GPUs to your VM instances by upgrading  your account. This can be done by clicking on the activate button in the cloud console. Please note that your credit card on file is charged for resources you use in excess of what's covered by any remaining credit.

Comment: upgraded, still cannot apply for quota